# Change Button Image in windows phone application

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I want to change the button image when I click on the button. Here is my xaml code:

```
<Button x:Name="bt1"

        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="OnClick" ClickMode="Press" Foreground="Red" Width="294"  >

<StackPanel>
<Image Name="Image" Source="/./Assets/RegIcons/ovenc.png" Height="80" Width="80"/>
```

And here is C# event code:

```
BitmapImage imgSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assests/RegIcons/tvc.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign this `BitmapImage` to `Image` control

```
Image.Source = imgSource
```

where `Image` is a **name** of an `Image` control

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking a separate Image Control I have set the Background property of button as Image.

Here is the XAML Code:

```
<Button x:Name="bt1" Height="150" Content="click" Click="OnClick">
```

Paste this code in the cs of the click event of your button bt1 :

```
        private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            bt1.Background = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assests/RegIcons/tvc.png", UriKind.Relative)) };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the universal application (Blank app) it works for me

```
bt1.Background = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:/Assests/RegIcons/tvc.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) };
```

or

```
            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
            Uri u = new Uri("ms-appx:/Images/timer.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            bmp.UriSource = u;
            // NOTE: change starts here
            Image i = new Image();
            i.Source = bmp;
            button1.Content = i;
```